# Equals sign in file name showing up in ascii

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a file in java.  Due to naming conventions, an equals sign (=) has to be appended to end of the file name.  So, foo=.txt is a valid example.  When I try and make the file with the command new File("foo=.txt"), the file name become foo%3D.txt but other ascii characters in the file name remain intact.  As a side note, this is for an android project and the file is being stored on an android device.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Where are you seeing the filename, and how are you storing it? I'd only expect %3D if something was doing URL encoding...

Comment: @Jon, yes.  It is a URL.  It is for an audio file.  The file is being stored on the device.  I am seeing this in Logcat.

Comment: So you're *not* just creating a file on the device - you should have mentioned URLs in your question. As it is, it's very unclear what you're doing, but using `new File("foo=.txt")` on the device will create a file called `foo=.txt`. When you fetch that in a URL it will indeed be `foo%3D.txt` due to URL encoding.

Comment: So, you are saying I need to encode the file name?

Comment: No. He's not.  Jon saying that it is showing up with %-encoding in the logs because you are logging a URL not a File.  The actual filename should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If creating File("foo=.txt") becomes foo%3D.txt, then reading File("foo=.txt") becomes reading foo%3D.txt. So if you are just trying to write and read the file, there should be no problem.

Comment: Ok, but i have a file 34)foo=.txt that shows up in logcat as 34)file%3D.txt.  What would cause this?

Comment: @dlucci: Logging a URL instead of a filename.